# Preventing Div With Position: Absolute from Overlapping the Fixed Header

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem that's totally blowing my mind...
I'm creating a classifieds website, and in the product container I'am adding a "New" icon in the container's top-left:

```
    .preview {
        position:static;
        width:250px;
        height:300px;
        float:left;
        outline:thin solid #999;
        margin-left:6px;
        margin-right:7px;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:20px;

        }

.preview .new_icon {
  position:absolute;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  margin:0;
  background-image: url(function_images/New-2.png);
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#header {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
height: 55px;
background-color:#fff;
top:0;

}
```

My website's header is fixed but when I scroll down, all the "New" icon container appears over the header. I want the header to be appear at the top of it. 
So any help??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try adding a z-index to your header. Also, putting your code in JSFiddle will help people solve your problem.

Comment: Something like z-index:9999999 :D

Comment: z-index actually solved it , by putting the header last loaded ... but isn't it incorrect to make the header last previewed ... 
other thing , there's ul list showing from the left side of it which also make the same problem ... so i need a technical solution !

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I second thoughts being shared above to bring on top u should use z-index. But little more detail will help to answer accurately.

Comment: okai , check the description again !!

Comment: Show a sample DOM or a jsfiddle, CSS on its own is of very little use.